# Matrix for a recurrence

Tags: matrices, number-theory

The matrix for a recurrence of the form $a_{k+2} = ka_{k+1}+a_{k}$ where $a_0 = 0$ and $a_1 = 1$ is given by $$\begin{bmatrix}k & 1\\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}^n = \begin{bmatrix} a_{k+1} & a_k \\ a_k & a_{k-1}\end{bmatrix}.$$ Is there a similar matrix for a recurrence of the form $a_{k+2} = ka_{k+1}-a_k$?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is very similar. If we write
$$\vec{a_k}=\left[\begin{array}{c}
a_{k+1} \\
a_{k}
\end{array}\right]$$
Then we have that
$$\left[\begin{array}{cc}
k & -1 \\
1 & 0
\end{array}\right]\vec{a_k}=\vec{a_{k+1}}$$
Which has solution
$$\vec{a_k}=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
k & -1 \\
1 & 0
\end{array}\right]^k\vec{a_0}
$$